# Is there a way to determine when 4 images have been loaded using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have 4 images on a page. I want to trigger a JS event once all 4 images are loaded. I of course can't be sure which order the images will be loaded in, so I can't trigger the event on the last image. One thought was to have a counter, but I can't think of the best way to check when that counter is equal to 4 as I don't like the idea of a setTimeout() checking every 200ms.

Any other ideas?

I'm using jQuery on the site, so I'm thinking that might be some help.

This is the image HTML code:

```
<img src="/images/hp_image-1.jpg" width="553" height="180" id="featureImg1" />
<img src="/images/hp_image-2.jpg" width="553" height="180" id="featureImg2" />
<img src="/images/hp_image-3.jpg" width="553" height="180" id="featureImg3" />
<img src="/images/hp_image-4.jpg" width="553" height="180" id="featureImg4" />
```

Answer (score 8):

As regards [Salty's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/414980/44084), it's best to use a closure to avoid global variables, like such:

```
$("img").load(function() {    
    var count = 0, numImages = $("img").size();

    return function () {
        if (++count === numImages) { 
            //All images have loaded    
        }
    };
}());
```

**[Edit]**

As per [jeroen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42139/jeroen), I replaced the hardcoded value of 4 (`count === 4`) with the jQuery `size` function as to allow for more flexibility within the function.

Comment: Unless these are the only four images on your page, however, you'll want to assign them a class or otherwise have some way to select just those four from your document.  (e.g. `$("img.dynloaded").load(…)`)

Comment: Yes exactly, because the $("img") selector is selecting every <img> tag on the page

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed, in combination with: var noImages = $("img").size(); instead of 4 to make it more flexible...

Answer (score 3):

```
count=0;
$("img").load(function() {
    count++;
    if(count==4) { //All images have loaded
        //Do something!
    }
});
```