# Is there a way to know when all the images have been downloaded from the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a simple html page where I want to load a stack of images. And I want to display one of them according to the user's cursor on the screen. Basically I'm trying to do something like this :

http://test.vostrel.net/jquery.reel/example/object-movie-camera-sequence/

I do this in two steps, in the first one I load low resolution images (60 images in less than two seconds) and in the second one when the user click for the first time I swap the low res for the high resolution images (60 images in about 10 seconds).

Those are my two functions :

```
function loadImages() {
    var imagesDOM;
    for (var j = 0 ; j < directoriesNumber ; j++) {
        imagesDOM = new Array();
        for (var i = 1 ; i < imageNumber + 1 ; i++) {
            images[i] = imageDirectory[j] + "/" + imageBasename + twoDigits(i) + imageExtension;
        }
        for (var i = 1 ; i < imageNumber + 1 ; i++) {
            imagesDOM[i] = new Image();
            imagesDOM[i].id = "image" + j + "_" + i;
            imagesDOM[i].src = images[i];
            $("#cadre").append(imagesDOM[i]);
        }
    }
}

function loadImagesHigh() {
    for (var j = 0 ; j < directoriesNumber ; j++) {
        for (var i = 1 ; i < imageNumber+1 ; i++) {
            images[i] = imageDirectoryHigh[j] + "/" + imageBasename + twoDigits(i) + imageExtension;
        }
        for (var i = 1 ; i < imageNumber+1 ; i++) {
            $("#image" + j + "_" + i).attr("src",images[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

So question is how can I monitor the downloads of the images on the client side : 4 out of 60 images loaded please wait...

I have checked this :
[Is there a way to determine when 4 images have been loaded using JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414976/is-there-a-way-to-determine-when-4-images-have-been-loaded-using-js)
But the src are written in the html.

**Solution**, thanks to Aaron Digulla, is as simple as adding the following event listener before assigning a value to src:

```
    $(imagesDOM[i]).load(function () {
            console.log("loaded");
        }
    );
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: How are you loading the images if not specifying the `src`?

Comment: Here : imagesDOM[i].src = images[i]; $("#cadre").append(imagesDOM[i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before assigning a value to `src`, attach an event listener to the image. You'll need two global variables which that contain the total image count and the number of images that have been loaded.

The question [Is there a way to determine when 4 images have been loaded using JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414976/is-there-a-way-to-determine-when-4-images-have-been-loaded-using-js) contains several examples how the event listener looks like.

**[EDIT]** OP finally used

```
$(imagesDOM[i]).load(function () {console.log("loaded")});
```

Comment: Exact solution for question is :   $(imagesDOM[i]).load(function () {console.log("loaded")}); Thanks, just the hint I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a similar thing recently and I plumped for manual use of jQuery deferred objects. Here's the principle:

```
//specify imgs to load and create a jQuery deferred object for each
var
imgs_to_load = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo2', 'bar2'], //etc
dfds = imgs_to_load.map(function() { return new $.Deferred; });

//wait for each img to load and resolve its corresponding deferred
imgs_to_load.forEach(function(filename, i) {
    var img = $('<img />', {src: filename+'.jpg'}).on('load', function() {
        dfds[i].resolve();
    });
});

//when all imgs loaded, do something
$.when.apply(null, dfds).then(function() { alert('all done'); });
```

So we make a deferred object for every image we wish to load. When the image loads, we manually resolve it, and when all deferreds are resolved we move on.

Comment: A bit complicated for me, adding event listener as suggested by Aaron was easier. Thanks anyway I'll put the "deferred thing" in the to read list.